# Difference between ulimit, launchctl, sysctl?

Tags: mac-osx, ulimit, sysctl, launchctl

When managing the limits of the operating system (specifically OSX), what is the difference and overlap between the functionality and history of these three tools:

1. `ulimit`
2. `launchctl`, `launchd`
3. `sysctl`

I found it confusing to adjust the maximum processes and open files limits on OSX.

Does it matter if some processes are launched via the terminal versus the GUI?

Possibly related:

- [Where are the default ulimits specified on OS X (10.5)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/15564/where-are-the-default-ulimits-specified-on-os-x-10-5)
- [How do ulimit -n and /proc/sys/fs/file-max differ?](https://serverfault.com/questions/122679/how-do-ulimit-n-and-proc-sys-fs-file-max-differ)

Answer (score 6):

### 1. ulimit

This is a builtin command of your shell (bash/ash/zsh etc).
It *temporarily* sets process limits for the current shell. This is not macOS specific by the way.

### 2. sysctl

Most unix-like (Linux/*BSD/macOS) systems set global limit/kernel settings via the `sysctl` command `/etc/sysctl.conf` config file.

Seems like [macOS does not honor `sysctl.conf` on startup anymore](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2781309?start=0&tstart=0). So on macOS, it looks like `sysctl` is merely usable for *temporarily* setting the global limits.

### 3. launchd / launchctl

For setting global limits in a persistent way, use `launchctl` on macOS.

Comment: The text under "launchd" doesn't actually talk about launchd (or launchctl, which the OP asked about).

Comment: Edited the answer to fix @NickChammas 's point.